# Importing Flask application to Elastic Beanstalk error: can't open file 'mod_wsgi': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am attempting to put my Flask application on Elastic Beanstalk (Amazon Web Services, EC2), but after uploading the files I receive a 500 error. Any thoughts on what could be the issue? The error log:

```
/opt/python/run/venv/bin/python3: can't open file 'mod_wsgi': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[Fri Sep 08 03:23:05.754341 2017] [:error] [pid 13619] [remote 128.12.244.5:31824] mod_wsgi (pid=13619): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Sep 08 03:23:05.754577 2017] [:error] [pid 13619] [remote 128.12.244.5:31824] mod_wsgi (pid=13619): SystemExit exception raised by WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/application.py' ignored.
[Fri Sep 08 03:23:05.754729 2017] [:error] [pid 13619] [remote 128.12.244.5:31824] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Sep 08 03:23:05.754992 2017] [:error] [pid 13619] [remote 128.12.244.5:31824]   File "/opt/python/current/app/application.py", line 11, in <module>
[Fri Sep 08 03:23:05.755007 2017] [:error] [pid 13619] [remote 128.12.244.5:31824]     application.run(debug=True)
[Fri Sep 08 03:23:05.755116 2017] [:error] [pid 13619] [remote 128.12.244.5:31824]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
[Fri Sep 08 03:23:05.755131 2017] [:error] [pid 13619] [remote 128.12.244.5:31824]     run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
[Fri Sep 08 03:23:05.755242 2017] [:error] [pid 13619] [remote 128.12.244.5:31824]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 737, in run_simple
[Fri Sep 08 03:23:05.755257 2017] [:error] [pid 13619] [remote 128.12.244.5:31824]     reloader_type)
[Fri Sep 08 03:23:05.755344 2017] [:error] [pid 13619] [remote 128.12.244.5:31824]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/_reloader.py", line 265, in run_with_reloader
[Fri Sep 08 03:23:05.755358 2017] [:error] [pid 13619] [remote 128.12.244.5:31824]     sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())
[Fri Sep 08 03:23:05.755429 2017] [:error] [pid 13619] [remote 128.12.244.5:31824] SystemExit: 2
```

My file structure is as follows: 
[file hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qc1xm.png)

My WSGI path is 
[config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwNmv.png)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I needed to wrap `application.run()` within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. This ensures that a local WSGI server is not loaded by default.

Source: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/deploying/mod_wsgi/